# Popen fails if command is a list and contains '&&' or '||'

Tags: python, popen

I have a python script that is running linux command to check if file exist:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen([ 'sudo', 'test', '-f', '/root/some_file', '&&', 'echo', 'True', '||', 'echo', 'False' ])
```

It produces error:

```
>>> test: extra argument `&&'
```

If pass the command as a single then it executes successfully:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen('sudo test -f /root/some_file && echo True || echo False' ], shell=True)
>>> True
```

Why does it fail if pass command as a list?

I have to use both && and || to check if the root's file exist so I can't convert it to the chain of separate commands as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467237/using-in-subprocess-popen-for-command-chaining)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467237/using-in-subprocess-popen-for-command-chaining ?

Comment: Yes it's similar. But my main concert is to use both && and || to check if the root's file exist so I can't convert it to the chain of separate commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this answer:
[Python: subprocess call with shell=False not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465700/python-subprocess-call-with-shell-false-not-working)

When calling Popen with shell=True you should use a string.
When calling Popen with shell=False you should use a list.

Using '&&' and '||' will only work if you are using shell=True as they require the shell.  This means that you can only get this to work using a string as your command, not a list.

If you are getting your command as a list, then you can just do something like:

```
" ".join(cmd_list)
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: No it doesn't actually. It prints out smth like help message:
`>>> usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V'

Comment: You are right, I just tried it.  I'll see if I can figure out what's going on here...